# Running/Stopping Django Development Server In Electron

Tags: python, django, server, electron

I am getting started with Electron and have some experience with Python and Django. Here's what I am trying to achieve,

1. Create a desktop application using Electron which will act as front-end.
2. Use python for back-end to do all the heavy lifting. By heavy lifting, I mean extensive text processing.
3. Use Django as bridge to show results produced by python in form of a simple web page (i.e. Electron)

What I know,

1. Electron feels far more usable, efficient and provides not-so-ugly UI components as against tkinter, etc. Thus the choice to stick with Electron.
2. From the googling done in past few days, I know node.js has some module to process text but really it isn't as efficient as python. Moreover, since I am more comfortable with python and the fact that I plan to play with natural language processing, I'd like to stick with python.
3. Using Django is more of a personal preference since I have used it before and there is one less thing to worry about (considering Electron has some learning curve).

Knowledge (albeit limited) I have,

1. [Rodeo](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/how-rodeo-works.html) has done something similar but they haven't gone into specific details. From this, all I know is it can be done. Just wandering around to get an answer to 'how'.
2. [Another article](https://codetalk.io/posts/2016-05-11-using-electron-with-haskell.html) which talks about running a Haskell server in Electron. From this, I tried to adapt to django with following implementation but again I get an error connection refused which is most likely due to server failing to run,

   ```
   function createBackendServer () {
     backendServer=child_process.spawn([path/to/venv/python],['manage.py','runserver'])}
   ```

With this I have had limited success. I have been able to run the Django server but I cannot kill the server. For doing so, I have used following code,

```
`app.on('will-quit', function() {
  backendServer.kill()
})`
```

and also,

```
`app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
    backendServer.kill()
  }
})`
```

none of these seem to work since I can still see an instance of python running and the url `127.0.0.1:8000` is still accessible from web browser. Keeping all this in mind, I have following questions,

1. How to stop Django server after the application closes?
2. Currently, to spawn a child, I am using absolute path which is grossly wrong. How do I turn it into relative path and run server using the python instance installed in virtual environment folder (venv/Scripts/python in windows)?

Answer (score 0):

in my code adding ***SIGNIT*** work well

```
mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
  mainWindow = null;
  py_process.kill('SIGINT');
});
```

Comment: I would love to test it out but the project requiring this is not something I am working on actively now. But that's for the heads up. I will mark is as an answer if I get it to working :)